# Settings only applying on second time sidebar opened REFrostedViewController

Tags: ios, sidebar

I'm trying to resize my sidebar, but the changes are only reflecting after the only time I open the sidebar.

```
@implementation MenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.frostedViewController setLimitMenuViewSize:TRUE];
    [self.frostedViewController setMenuViewSize:CGSizeMake(200, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
}
```

If someone could help me, that would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put these configurations in the `REFrostedViewController` subclass. For example (supposing you are using storyboards), you could configure the menu right below the view controllers assignment, e.g. (but, remember, you can put the config everywhere in the REFrostedViewController initialization code)

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.contentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentViewController"];
    self.menuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuViewController"];

    self.limitMenuViewSize  = YES;
    self.menuViewSize       = CGSizeMake(200.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
}
```

Doing this configuration in the MenuViewController `viewDidLoad` method causes the config to be applied only AFTER the menu view is loaded for the **first** time, and so your changes show up only the **second** time.

Just put the code in the `REFrostedViewController` subclass (or even in the contentViewController you are using) and you should be fine.

Comment: I figured this out, but my internet went out. But thanks anyways.